# Relation between two gradient dynamics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-equations, gradient-flows

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ is a **nonnegative real analytic** function and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a **strongly convex smooth** function with a **surjective** gradient $\nabla g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it possible that the solution $x:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ to
$$\dot{x}=-\nabla f(x), \quad x(0)=x_0$$
is bounded for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., $\|x(t)\|\leq c(x_0)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$ for some constant $c(x_0)>0$ (assume $c(x_0)$ is smooth in $x_0$), but the solution to the Hessian Riemannian gradient flow
$$\dot{x}=-\left(\nabla^2g(x)\right)^{-1}\nabla f(x), \quad x(0)=x_0,$$
where $\nabla^2g$ denotes the Hessian of $g$, is unbounded for some $x_0$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449520/relation-between-hessian-riemannian-gradient-flow-and-euclidean-gradient-flow#comment1161516_449520), exactly, and I apologise for being inadvertently obscure.  Since my other comments are now irrelevant, I have deleted them.

Comment: so do we have any information on $c(x_{0})$? Does it diverge as $\|x_{0}\|_{2}\to +\infty$?

Comment: @ThomasKojar Yes, we can imagine if we initialize farther and farther from the origin, then even if the corresponding solution is still bounded (or even converges),  the bound may be larger and larger. But I guess we can assume $c(x_0)$ is a smooth function of $x_0$.

Comment: so are you worried that the solution of the Hessian-flow will diverge? And are you also trying to get a $\tilde{c}(x_{0})$ bound for $x(t)$ solving the Hessian-flow?

Comment: @ThomasKojar Yes, like I know the gradient flow under Euclidean metric will always be bounded (or converges if you like), I am worried that if I use such a nice $g$ to induce a new Riemannian metric, and under this new metric, the solution goes to infinity as $t\to\infty$. For the $\tilde{c}(x_0)$ bound I don't care. I just need qualitative analysis result. By the way, I know the general case may be too hard and it would be very nice to have some results for a special $g$ like I listed in the post.

Comment: I wonder if you can use the fact that the second problem is equivalent to this: $$\frac{d}{dt}\nabla g(x) = -\nabla f(x)$$ together with the substitution $z = \nabla g(x)$; you've said that $\nabla g$ is surjective.

Comment: @DanielShapero Thanks for your comments. I noticed the fact you mentioned, but can you explain in a bit more detailed way that how it connects the trajectory of original gradient flow and the Riemannian one?

Comment: I don't have a fully formed thought there, just that it's neat? The system $\frac{d}{dt}\nabla h(x) = -\nabla f(x)$ is a kind of generalized gradient flow as long as $h$ is a nice convex function. So you're asking about two choices, $h = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$ or $h = g$. Just a wild guess here, what if you do some homotopy trick -- take $$h_s = (1 - s)\cdot\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + s\cdot g(x)$$ for $s$ in [0, 1]? Something something continuity of solutions w.r.t. a parameter...

Comment: @DanielShapero Nice idea. Thanks. I will have a try.